# Merging 2 nearly identical functions in perl

Tags: perl, code-duplication

I have a script that gets some data from a website. The data comes in JSON format and the site offers an option to "flatten" the JSON output into a single JSON object, or leave it as multiple objects.

The script has options that allow for converting the JSON data to YAML (whether flattened or not), or leaving it in JSON format.

In addition the script colorizes the values in both formats.

In order to accomplish the coloring, I currently have 2 functions, one for JSON colorization, and one for YAML colorization.

Colorization itself is achieved with Term::ANSIColor, by searching and replacing the text in either a Scalar or an Array, depending on which output format the data is in.

I would like to get this down to one function in order to reduce the code duplication, but I am at a loss for how to accomplish this.

**To be clear**, the main focus of this question, for clarity's sake, is how to make one of the colorization functions reusable so that it can work on both the YAML and the JSON output. Because the search patterns are very very similar, and the replacement patterns are identical, I feel like it should be really easy to accomplish this but I'm drawing a blank on how to do it.

```
use JSON;
use YAML::Tiny;

sub colorize_yaml
{
    my $OUTPUT                                                                               = shift;
    my $OPTIONS                                                                              = shift;

    if (ref $OUTPUT eq 'SCALAR')
    {
        foreach (${$OUTPUT})
        {

            # Hide this if debugging is disabled, else show it and color it
            if (!$OPTIONS->{debug})
            {
                s{(statusCode|success|dataExist|verumModelObjectName):\ [a-zA-Z0-9]+\n}
{}gxms;
            }
            else
            {
            s{(statusCode|success|dataExist|verumModelObjectName):}
{$OPTIONS->{color} ? BOLD YELLOW $1 . ':', BOLD GREEN : $1 . ':'}gxmse;
            }

            # Colorize 5 segment flat output
            s{([a-zA-Z0-9]+:)([a-zA-Z0-9]+:)([a-zA-Z0-9]+:)([a-zA-Z0-9]+:)([a-zA-Z0-9]+:\ )}
{$OPTIONS->{color} ? BOLD CYAN $1, BOLD YELLOW $2, BOLD MAGENTA $3, BOLD RED $4, RESET $5: $1 . $2 . $3 . $4 . $5}gxmse;

            # Colorize 4 segment flat output
            s{([a-zA-Z0-9]+:)([a-zA-Z0-9]+:)([a-zA-Z0-9]+:)([a-zA-Z0-9]+:\ )}
{$OPTIONS->{color} ? BOLD CYAN $1, BOLD YELLOW $2, BOLD MAGENTA $3, RESET $4 : $1 . $2 . $3 . $4}gxmse;

            # Colorize 3 segment flat output
            s{([a-zA-Z0-9]+:)([a-zA-Z0-9]+:)([a-zA-Z0-9]+:\ )}
{$OPTIONS->{color} ? BOLD CYAN $1, BOLD YELLOW $2, RESET $3 : $1 . $2 . $3}gxmse;

            # Colorize 2 segment flat output
            s{([a-zA-Z0-9]+:)([a-zA-Z0-9]+:\ )}
{$OPTIONS->{color} ? BOLD CYAN $1, RESET $2 : $1 . $2}gxmse;

            # Colorize values in all output
            s{(:\ )}
{$OPTIONS->{color} ? $1 . BOLD GREEN : $1}gxmse;

            # Reset colors before newlines so that the next line starts with a clean color pattern.
            s{\n}
{$OPTIONS->{color} ? RESET "\n" : "\n"}gxmse;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        pretty_print_error("WARNING: Unable to colorize YAML output\n", $OPTIONS->{color});
        return;
    }

    return;
}

sub colorize_json
{
    my $OUTPUT                                                                               = shift;
    my $OPTIONS                                                                              = shift;

    if (ref $OUTPUT eq 'ARRAY')
    {
        foreach (@{$OUTPUT})
        {
            if ($OPTIONS->{debug})
            {
                s{(statusCode|success|dataExist|verumModelObjectName):}
{$OPTIONS->{color} ? BOLD YELLOW $1 . ':', BOLD GREEN : $1 . ':'}gxmse;
            }
            else
            {
                s{(statusCode|success|dataExist|verumModelObjectName):\ [a-zA-Z0-9]+\n}
{}gxms;
            }

            # Colorize 5 segment flat output
            s{^([a-zA-Z0-9]+:)([a-zA-Z0-9]+:)([a-zA-Z0-9]+:)([a-zA-Z0-9]+:)([a-zA-Z0-9]+:\ .*$)}
{$OPTIONS->{color} ? BOLD CYAN $1, BOLD YELLOW $2, BOLD MAGENTA $3, BOLD RED, $4, RESET $5: $1 . $2 . $3 . $4 . $5}gxmse;

            # Colorize 4 segment flat output
            s{^([a-zA-Z0-9]+:)([a-zA-Z0-9]+:)([a-zA-Z0-9]+:)([a-zA-Z0-9]+:\ )}
{$OPTIONS->{color} ? BOLD CYAN $1, BOLD YELLOW $2, BOLD MAGENTA $3, RESET $4 : $1 . $2 . $3 . $4}gxmse;

            # Colorize 3 segment flat output
            s{^([a-zA-Z0-9]+:)([a-zA-Z0-9]+:)([a-zA-Z0-9]+:\ )}
{$OPTIONS->{color} ? BOLD CYAN $1, BOLD YELLOW $2, RESET $3 : $1 . $2 . $3}gxmse;

            # Colorize 2 segment flat output
            s{^([a-zA-Z0-9]+:)([a-zA-Z0-9]+:\ )}
{$OPTIONS->{color} ? BOLD CYAN $1, RESET $2 : $1 . $2}gxmse;

            # Colorize values in all output
            s{(:\ )}
{$OPTIONS->{color} ? $1 . BOLD GREEN : $1}gxmse;

            # Reset colors before newlines so that the next line starts with a clean color pattern.
            s{$}
{$OPTIONS->{color} ? RESET '' : ''}gxmse;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        pretty_print_error("WARNING: Unable to colorize JSON output.\n", $OPTIONS->{color});
        return;
    }

    return;
}
```

JSON converted to YAML

```
---
message: Success
ObjectList:
  -
    assetName: xxxxxxxx
    backupAsset:
      -
        backupFlag: xxxxxxxx
        fullyCertified: xxxxxxxx
```

Flattened JSON converted to YAML

```
---
message: Success
verumObjectList:
  -
    assetName: xxxxxxxx
    backupAsset:backupFlag: xxxxxxxx
    backupAsset:fullyCertified: xxxxxxxx
```

JSON (the data in JSON format is stripped by the script to make it plain text)

```
assetName: xxxxxxxx
backupFlag: xxxxxxxx
fullyCertified: xxxxxxxx
message: Success
```

Flattened JSON (the data in JSON format is stripped by the script to make it plain text)

```
assetName: xxxxxxxx
backupAsset:backupFlag: xxxxxxxx
backupAsset:fullyCertified: xxxxxxxx
message: Success
```

---

The correct answer is awarded to @zdim though I did have to tweak the code slightly.

I'm posting my updated code below.

```
use JSON;
use YAML::Tiny;

sub colorize_output
{
    my $OUTPUT   = shift;
    my $OPTIONS  = shift;

    my $RE_START = $EMPTY;
    my $RE_END   = q{\ };

    if (ref $OUTPUT eq $EMPTY)
    {   
        pretty_print_error("WARNING: Unable to colorize output.\n", 
            $OPTIONS->{color});
        return;
    }   
    elsif (ref $OUTPUT eq 'ARRAY')
    {   
        $RE_START = q{^};
        $RE_END   = q{\ .*};
    }   

    my $ANCHOR    = q{[a-zA-Z0-9]+:};
    my $PATTERN   = qq{($ANCHOR)};

    Readonly my $SEGMENT_LIMIT => 4;

    my $VERUM_RE = qr{(statusCode|success|dataExist|verumModelObjectName):}xms;

    my ($SEGMENT_2PART_RE, $SEGMENT_3PART_RE, $SEGMENT_4PART_RE, $SEGMENT_5PART_RE)
        = map { 
            qr{$RE_START}xms . ($PATTERN x $ARG) . qr{($ANCHOR$RE_END)}xms 
        } 1..$SEGMENT_LIMIT;

    foreach ((ref $OUTPUT eq 'SCALAR')?${$OUTPUT}:@{$OUTPUT})
    {   

        # Hide this if debugging is disabled, else show it and color it
        if (!$OPTIONS->{debug})
        {   
            s{$VERUM_RE\ [a-zA-Z0-9]+}{}gxms;
        }   
        else
        {   
            s{$VERUM_RE}
             {$OPTIONS->{color} ? BOLD YELLOW $1 . ':', BOLD GREEN : $1 . ':'}gxmse;
        }   

        # Colorize sections in flat output
        if ($OPTIONS->{color})
        {   
            s{$SEGMENT_5PART_RE}
             {BOLD CYAN $1, BOLD YELLOW $2, BOLD MAGENTA $3, BOLD RED $4, RESET $5}gxmse;
            s{$SEGMENT_4PART_RE}
             {BOLD CYAN $1, BOLD YELLOW $2, BOLD MAGENTA $3, RESET $4}gxmse;
            s{$SEGMENT_3PART_RE}
             {BOLD CYAN $1, BOLD YELLOW $2, RESET $3}gxmse;
            s{$SEGMENT_2PART_RE}
             {BOLD CYAN $1, RESET $2}gxmse;

            # Colorize values in all output
            s{(:\ )}{$1 . BOLD GREEN}gxmse;

            # Reset colors before newlines or next entry in the list so that
            # the next line starts with a clean color pattern.
            s{(\n|$)}{RESET $1}gxmse;
        }   
    }   

    return;
}
```

Comment: We need to have example data for both formats. It would be best if you actually wrote a unit test and included that. For an example of how to write unit tests for the coloring stuff, feel free to borrow from [my tests of the module Dancer2::Logger::Console::Colored](https://github.com/burnersk/Dancer2-Logger-Console-Colored/blob/master/t/logger_console_colored.t).

Comment: If the task is to colorize YAML, you could also have a look at [YAML::PP](http://p3rl.org/YAML::PP) (disclaimer: from myself). It can highlight YAML, and since YAML is (almost) a superset of JSON, it can colorize JSON, too. But the highlighting is different currently from what you want, i think.

Comment: @tinita Unfortunately, the machine running the code and downloading the data does not have external web access, only access internally and to specific repositories built by our engineers. Because of this, I am using YAML::Tiny and I am unable to install YAML::PP from CPAN or elsewhere. :-(

Comment: @simbabque I will look into unit tests. I will post sample data in all 4 formats (json, flattened json, json converted to yaml, and flattened json converted to yaml) -- soon

Comment: Ok. Great. I have about one and a half hours of train ride left. :)

Comment: @simbabque looks like your test is against a module. I'm not writing a module. Is it still possible to do? What changes are necessary to make a unit test of a script that is not a module?

Comment: Well, for this example you can just have a file that includes Test::More (et al) and the functions you want to test. And then run that. If you want to keep those tests around, a good approach would be to `do "script.pl";` at the top of your unit test file. That will give you the functions. But it will also run code, so the architecture of your script matters. For now I was just suggesting a test because showing us expected output with terminal colors is going to be ... interesting. ;)

Comment: Ahah yeah, colors matter, but for the example, not so much. I can work out the colors themselves, I just want to deduplicate as much as I can. As you can tell from the code, the majority of it is duplicate, the only real differences are checking for ARRAY ref in colorize_json vs checking for SCALAR ref in colorize_yaml, and the use of ^ and $ in colorize_json vs \n in colorize_yaml

Comment: Why is the difference in the pattern needed?

Comment: You need to also show us how you are calling the function. Either add the parsing code, or dump out the data structures after it's been imported. I don't particularly care about where it's coming from for this problem.

Comment: The difference in the pattern is needed because in converting from JSON to YAML, the data is dumped into a scalar by ```Yaml::Tiny```'s ```Dump``` method, which forces newlines to be present. In raw JSON format, I converted the data to an array first, as it was easier to strip JSON tags from each line of output individually rather than doing it as one giant string. Since we're not stripping anything from the YAML converted output, it was easier to leave it as one giant string.

Comment: Oh so you want to highlight it and then output the JSON or YAML to the screen? Now I understand. Is highlighting the values before you convert it an option?

Comment: Yes, but then ```YAML::Tiny``` chokes on the highlighting characters. :-( YAML::PP wouldn't choke, but it unfortunately cannot be installed on this host without jumping through some massive enterprise hoops.

Comment: You seem to have written a single-purpose JSON/YAML parser. I think I would convert both to Perl data and display and colourise that instead.

Comment: One thing I don't understand ... the code under `foreach` loop in these functions appear identical.  Is that correct? You are only asking how to make it process either scalarref or arrayref?

Comment: Suggestions on how to accomplish that are greatly welcome. The only real need for ```use JSON``` and ```use YAML::Tiny``` is for flipping the JSON data from the website, to YAML format for the purposes of displaying the data on screen. If I can do it with Perl data, and still get the output in either plain text or YAML, that would be so much better.

Comment: @zdim almost identical. The pattern match part of the ```s///``` lines is ***slightly*** different.

Comment: ok, I see now ... that `^` ... that's it?

Comment: Broke up a few very long lines -- it is hard to follow code when one has to scroll far to the right. By all means please roll back if you don't like it (or of course touch up if some details are a bother).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answers the question of how to refactor these functions, without any broader context.

One difference is the input: it is either a scalarref or an arrayref.

The more involved two other differences are in the regex: arrayref patterns are anchored and their last alphanumeric pattern ends with `\ .*$`, while scalarref ones are not anchored and their last match ends with an escaped space.

Finally, if `$OPTIONS->{color}` is false then the whole pattern is replaced by itself, in all cases; so the variable doesn't change. Then the condition should be pulled out.

```
sub colorize_yaml_json {
    my ($OUTPUT, $OPTIONS) = @_;

    my $anchor = '';
    my $last   = qr{\ };
    my @iter_refs;

    if    (ref $OUTPUT eq 'SCALAR') { @iter_refs = $$OUTPUT }
    elsif (ref $OUTPUT eq 'ARRAY')  { 
        @iter_refs = @$OUTPUT;
        $anchor = qr{^};
        $last   = qr{\ .*$};
    }
    else {
        pretty_print_error(...);
        return;
    }

    my $anc  = qr{[a-zA-Z0-9]+:};  # alphanumeric with colon
    my $patt = qr{($anc)};

    my ($seg2_re, $seg3_re, $seg4_re, $seg5_re) = map { 
        qr/$anchor/ . ($patt x $_) . qr/($anc$last)/ 
    } 1..4;

    foreach (@iter_refs) {
        if ($OPTIONS->{debug}) {
            ...
        }        
        if ($OPTIONS->{color}) {
            s{$seg5_re}{BOLD CYAN $1, ... }gxmse;
            ...
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

The `map` assembles the whole pattern for the four cases, by stacking the alphanumeric (with `:`) pattern `$patt` the needed 2–5 times, using `x N` for `1..4` and then appending the last pattern.

The unpleasant complication is that each of base patterns `$anc` need be captured.

I could only test this on my mock-up data so please check carefully (as always!).

There is also the other issue of how to best handle the whole scenario, but that wasn't the question and so there isn't enough information to deal with it without much guessing.

Comment: @Speeddymon  The initial code wasn't doing quite as in your question, corrected.

Comment: Just got back from a meeting and will try this out. Thanks!

Comment: After playing around with it some, it turns out that the ```map``` function is compiling the variables properly, but is not producing the desired output.

Instead of declaring the 4 $seg?_re variables with the ```map```, I had to declare them as below:

`my $seg2_re = qr{$ANCHOR${patt}($anc$LAST)}xms;
my $seg3_re = qr{$ANCHOR${patt}${patt}($anc$LAST)}xms;
my $seg4_re = qr{$ANCHOR${patt}${patt}${patt}($anc$LAST)}xms;
my $seg5_re = qr{$ANCHOR${patt}${patt}${patt}${patt}($anc$LAST)}xms;`

Comment: @Speeddymon Alright, thank you for feedback!  In my limited tests in worked, apparently I pushed it too far.  Will fix or otherwise update (write them one by one if `map` can't be leveraged).  (Need to run right now)

Comment: I took care, added the updated code into my OP and awarded you the answer. Thank you for your help. It was really just a matter of needing to understand that you *can* use variable names in the matching section of ```s///```

Comment: @Speeddymon  Thank you for such good feedback and for the attribution. The problem was `$patt{2}` -- when `$patt` has capturing parenthesis it doesn't work as intended.  I've changed that to `$patt x 2` (in `map` so "2" is really `$_`) and it now works in my more extensive (still mock-up) tests.  Another problem would be that I had code which first replaces 2 instances, then 3 ... that wouldn't work; fixed.  Finally,  add flags in `s{}{}FLAGS` as suitable.

Comment: @Speeddymon Another omission was `$OUTPUT` instead of `$$OUTPUT` (no need for parens); fixed

Comment: @Speeddymon  Added a comment at the end, cleaned up a little throughout

Comment: Thanks for the updates. It didn't occur to me to split up the pattern in the `map` in order to get the desired result. Also, thanks for the feedback on the substitution. I had originally done it that way because of perlcritic complaining that the function was too complex, but with some other changes I made, it reduced the complexity enough that I was able to wrap it in an `if`, as you had suggested. which definitely is easier to read!

Comment: One more question. I noticed in your code you used `qr//` throughout, rather than just `q//` and `qq//`, and then having `qr//` in the map itself be the only `qr//`-- Is there a reason for that? Having only the two `qr//` in the map, with the rest being `q//` and `qq//` seems to work fine for me.

Comment: @Speeddymon    The `map` way is more compact and general but spelling them out as you have it now is easier for review. Then if all is well I'll  rephrase the last part to remove the conditionals ("_It appears that..._", "_if this is indeed so..._").

Comment: @Speeddymon  The `qr` is better for regex, in general, since one may then use full regex inside.  However, for most of the common regex patterns forming a string with `q()` works as well.  I'd be careful with double quotes `qq()` since interpolation may result in surprises (and regex is going to do it "knowingly" anyway once the variable is evaluated for the pattern).  I don't know why I was inconsistent; I think the `q()` (that was in the `map`?) remained from some testing.  Now they are all `qr`.

Comment: @Speeddymon  One more comment, on "Perl Critic."  It is a useful resource, no question.  However, it _is not_ a definitive code checker -- and it is not meant to be that.  This is an excellent example.  It is plain better, by a long shot, to pull that condition out.  If Critic doesn't think so ... I'll review the function and if there is nothing I want to do I'll leave it; the "critic" can't tell me how to write code, and if you look at "Perl Best Practices" (the book on which it is tightly based), it doesn't intend to.  That said, I run it every now and then, as a check and food for thought.